# Convert CURL command to PHP for use with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How do I convert the curl command below to PHP used with Laravel?

```
curl -X POST -F "images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=xxxxa12345&version=2016-05-20"
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this package, this is a super easy curl wrapper for laravel
https://github.com/ixudra/curl

so it would look like

```
   use Ixudra\Curl\Facades\Curl;

   $response = Curl::to('https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=xxxxa12345&version=2016-05-20')
    ->withContentType('multipart/form-data')
    ->withData(['images_file' => file_get_contents("yourfile")])
    ->containsFile()
    ->post();
```

Comment: Im getting syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) on the ->withData line

Comment: yeah it missed a brace, i converted array to short syntax so it's clearer sorry for this :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to **upload file with curl php**:

```
function uploadFileWithCURL($fullFilePath, $targetURL)
{
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        $curlFile = curl_file_create($fullFilePath);
    } else {
        $curlFile = '@' . realpath($fullFilePath);
    }
    $post = array('file_contents' => $curlFile);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $targetURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$result = uploadFileWithCURL('path/to/your/fruitbowl.jpg','https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=xxxxa12345&version=2016-05-20');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Http** facade and call the **attach** method, this method accepts the name of the file and its contents

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::attach(
    'images_file', '/home/user/fruitbowl.jpg', 'fruitbowl.jpg'
)->post('https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=xxxxa12345&version=2016-05-20'
)->json();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#multi-part-requests

Comment: Could you please elaborate to help us to understand your code?